# router blocking most traffic except for apps like facebook

Tags: router, wireless-router, firewall

Hi I have a really strange issue, my cable model is a SMART/RG router.  Its been working fine until I decided to test out OPENDDNS family shield, I enabled it but it made things slower so I decided to disable it however disabling this blocks all traffic except for apps on my phone like facebook... its probably some weird firewall issue. Thus now it has to be left "enabled" and would only work when its on. Does anyone know how to solve this?! thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to solve router problems like is to rest it to original (out of the box) setup and then go through the connection setup again

Comment: @John dude thanks! simple and elegant.  Weird issue though

Comment: Is is working now?  I will post as answer if now working. It does appear to be working.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the easiest way to solve router problems like is to reset it to original (out of the box) setup and then go through the connection setup again.  This usually works.

Comment: thanks - this works well.  A worry I had was that was that my ISP had some settings so I made a backup of the setting before saved just in case.  Also, I reset through the web interface instead of the hardware.  Seem to work fine afterwards. However, with that said I'm still very curious as to what happened.